Remove part of column name from multiple data frames (names change by year)
I have multiple data frames ab2013, ab2014, ab2015.
The column names in each have subscripts that follow the last two digits (years) of the file names:
in ab2013, I have vara_13, varb_13
in ab2014, I have vara_14, varb_14
in ab2015, I have vara_15, varb_15
I would like to remove "_13", "_14", "_15" from the column names. I know how to do this per file:
for(col in 1:ncol(ab2013)) {
  colnames(ab2013)[col]=sub("_13.*", "", colnames(ab2013)[col])
}

I would be grateful for help on how to do this for all files in a loop.

You might want to use a modification of list_of_files = lapply(list_of_files, \(i) setNames(i, sub("_.*","",colnames(i)))); e.g.: names(cars)=c("a_13", "b_14"); list_of_files=list(cars, cars).
